# Phusion Passenger Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, makefile, passenger

I just upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 and I have a problem starting phusion passenger.  I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/ext/nginx/../common/libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o): undefined reference to symbol 'round@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'round@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/root-passenger-23103/nginx-1.0.5'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Was wondering if there is a fix for this issue or if it is a known issue that may be fixed soon.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To fix this problem install gcc-4.4.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4 g++-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
rvmsudo CC=gcc-4.4 passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Answer (score 0):

The rvmsudo solution did not work for me, as I had the passenger gem already installed, and rvm wanted to use that instead of the system-wide one that rvmsudo installed.

What **did** work for me is:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4 g++-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
CC=gcc-4.4 passenger start
```